# Como centralizar verticalmente o conteúdo de um elemento?

Tags: css, html

Estou tentando centralizar verticalmente o conteúdo de um elemento que tem `position: absolute`.

Consegui fazer o conteúdo se posicionar da metade para baixo do *container*, no entanto, da metade para cima o espaço fica "sobrando".

Como posso resolver isso apenas utilizando [css](/questions/tagged/css)?

Eis o meu código até o momento:

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
        <p>Subtítulo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

A ideia é que o elemento `.container` sobreponha o elemento-pai, como se fosse um indicador de *loading* em cima de apenas um elemento na página.

Comment: É realmente necessário que **o elemento** tenha posição absoluta? Ou apenas seu contêiner?

Comment: Atualizei a questão com uma melhor descrição do objetivo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Desta forma independe do conteúdo:

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -50% );
    -moz-transform: translateY( -50% );
    transform: translateY( -50% );
}
```

Veja no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ARYA8/)

Comment: transform é CSS3?

Comment: Não, já o translateX e translateY estou tentando descobrir se é implementação nova.

Comment: É isto mesmo!!!

Answer (score 19):

Utilizando o exemplo dado, o problema está no elemento com a classe `content` cujo mesmo não tem uma altura definida, o que não permite calcular o centro do mesmo.

Mesmo ao atribuir uma altura, sendo um elemento com uma posição absoluta, o mesmo está numa camada superior a dos restantes elementos, o que faz com que a altura do mesmo não seja calculada em função dos restantes elementos.

## Solução

Uma das possíveis soluções passa por indicar ao browser que os elementos devem assumir os comportamentos visuais das tabelas:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
        <p>Subtítulo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    display:table;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Veja no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/vUd42/)

Ainda assim, é necessário retirar a definição `position:absolute` pois a mesma entra em conflito com a nova definição `display:table-cell` que na sua essência não pode ser posicionada de forma absoluta uma vez que está sempre relativa à tabela onde se encontra inserida.

Dependendo do objectivo final, pode ser aplicado ao elemento com a classe `content` a definição `position:relative` de forma a poder fazer do mesmo um contentor para outros elementos filhos.

Comment: Adicione `body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}` que seu exemplo fica ainda melhor (:

Answer (score 10):

[Esse artigo](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) (em inglês) descrebe uma variedade de maneiras de se atingir esse objetivo. Para seu caso particular (elemento com posição absoluta) eu recomendaria o método "esticar":

Coloque seu elemento com todas as posições (`top`, `left`, `bottom` e `right`) como `0`. Isso fará com que ele "se estique" para ocupar a tela inteira. Mas como ele é menor que a tela, colocar a margem como `auto` fará com que ela se auto-ajuste às dimensões reais do elemento.

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;    
}
```

Veja no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7NKv/4/).

Note que é neessário especificar uma altura para que esse método funcione como esperado.

Answer (score 4):

Cara, pra centralizar tanto vertical quanto horizontal neste caso...você precisa definir o tamanho do elemento, e além do top:50% usar margin-top negativo com **metade** da altura do 
elemento.

Por exemplo no seu código:

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    height:120px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se for para centralizar uma DIV em uma página, por enquanto não criaram nenhuma maneira para fazer isso, agora existem 3 maneiras para fazer isso:

1. **Utilizando uma DIV Absoluta**: você coloca todo o seu conteúdo da página em uma div única e esta é então inserida com as tags `div {position:absolute;top:50%;left:50% margin:-25%;}`
2. **Transformando a página em uma tabela**: no CSS da tag `<body>` coloque para que ela seja exibida como uma tabela: `body{display:table}` e então nas  coloque para que estas sejam exibidas como cédulas da tabela: `div{display:table-cell;}`, isso vai centralizar verticalmente.
3. **Definindo o tamanho do HTML e do BODY como 100%**: quando o `<html>` e o `<body>` são definidos com uma altura fixa eles podem ser usados como referência para a altura das `<div>`. Para isso faça: `html,body{height:100%}` assim será possível usar no atributo margin o valor de margin top assim: `div{margin-top:10%}`

Answer (score 1):

Eu fazia o método de table-cell até descobrir um melhor ainda:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Aplique isso ao elemento que deseja centralizar verticalmente. Não é necessário nenhum controle de altura no elemento pai e muito menos no elemento desejado.

Lembrando que meu método é bem parecido com um postado aqui, mas estou utilizando position: relative, ao invés de absolute.