# Como centralizar horizontalmente uma div dentro de outra?

Tags: css, html, div, css-centering

Como eu posso centralizar horizontalmente uma `div` que está dentro de outra `div` utilizando apenas CSS?

No caso, podemos assumir que `div` externa `outer` tem a largura de 100%.

```html
<div id="outer">  
  <div id="inner">Este é o elemento interno.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Essa pergunta deveria ser protegida. Servirá de referência para muita gente no futuro.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Existem várias maneiras.** Estes métodos são dividos em "largura definida" e "largura variável" pois depende da sua necessidade de implementação.

Algumas são semanticamente mais recomendadas, porém ainda não funcionam em quase nenhum navegador, outras já existem há muito tempo e continuam sendo utilizadas pois apresentam compatibilidade superior.

## Largura Definida

Existem três métodos populares para fazer isso, são eles:

### Margem Automática

```css
#inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%; /* Altere para o valor da largura desejada. */
}
```

O que nós fizemos aqui foi informar o valor `auto` para as propriedades de `margin-left` e `margin-right` que vai calcular automaticamente a diferença de espaço restante e magicamente centralizar o seu elemento horizontalmente. É importante lembrar que a mesma regra não vale para [centralizar um objeto verticalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/).

**Internet Explorer 6:** Esta versão do Internet Explorer necessita da adição da propriedade `text-align: center;` neste código.

**Internet Explorer 8:** Se você tiver problemas de compatibilidade com o Internet Explorer 8, é melhor que adicione a propriedade `display: table;` neste código.

### Posição Absoluta

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px; /* A metade de sua largura. */
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px; /* O valor que você desejar. */
}
```

Embora utilize margem negativa e posição absoluta, este é o método mais compatível que existe.

**Atenção:** tome cuidado para que a utilização do `position: absolute;` não comprometa a integridade do seu layout.

### [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

Embora mais recomendado, este método ainda está sendo disseminado e permanece como recurso experimental dos navegadores, por este motivo ainda é muito instável para ser utilizado.

```css
#outer {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  width: 200px; /* Ou a que você quiser. */
}
```

## Largura Variável

Existem duas maneiras de posicionar com larguras variáveis, a mais compatível para este fim é com a utilização do `inline-block`.

### inline-block

```css
#outer {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

O que vai fazer com que o elemento `#inner` fique centralizado é a presença da propriedade `text-align: center;` no `#outer`. Porém é importante ressaltar que o nosso amigo **Internet Explorer 7** e inferiores não suportam a propriedade `display: inline-block;`.

### CSS Transforms

Entretanto, se você só preocupado com navegadores que já suportam CSS3, é possível fazer isso de forma mais elegante e simples.

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Isso também [serve para posicionamentos verticais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166/336). :)

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar exemplos práticos aqui, talvez via jsfiddle.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 5):

Eu costumo usar:

```
.pai{width: 100%}
.filho{width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

O .pai está 100% caso haja alguma imagem que ocupe 100% da tela, o .filho está em 960px para ficar alinhado em monitores com 1024px, assim não irá criar scroll horizontal e ter que usar (overflow-x: hidden).

Se você usar o código que citei acima, terá uma **div** centralizada.
Se por acaso a sua div .pai tiver uma imagem de background, ao dar scroll ela irá diminuir alinhando para a esquerda, lhe aconselho a fazer o seguinte:

```
.pai img {background-image: url('../images/teste;jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center top};
```

Com isso, a sua imagem sempre ficará alinhada no centro e no topo. :D

Answer (score 2):

Podemos usar o famoso método pouco ortodoxo :

```
#outer { width: 100%;}
#inner { width: 1000px; left: 50%; margin-left: -500px;}
```

Assumindo que sua div inner terá 1000px de largura mas você também poderá ajustar para qualquer tamanho sempre colocando a metade no margin-left.