# Centralizar form etc, deixar no centro da tela

Tags: html

Eu gostaria de saber como centralizar qualquer coisa no css, tipo, deixar no centro da tela. Alguém pode me ajudar? Eu estou usando HTML5.

Comment: Essa pergunta ja foi respondida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/806/como-centralizar-horizontalmente-uma-div-dentro-de-outra

Comment: O que você quer centralizar? uma <div> <p> texto?

Comment: Eu quero centralizar um formulário, deixar ele no centro da tela.

Answer (score 0):

no pai você utiliza:

```
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
```

e no filho(no caso o form):

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
```

lembrando que isso só centraliza horizontalmente. e o filho deve ter um tamanho menor que o pai.

Comment: Não deu certo cara.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode forçar o body a ocupar toda a vertical área visível do viewport:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Numa DIV pai você também faz com que ela use toda a área vertical e posicionamento relativo:

```
position: relative;
min-height: 100vh;
```

No form, você centraliza o início do mesmo no centro da tela e translada 50% do seu tamanho para centralizá-lo:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%)
```

Segue exemplo completo:

```
<style>
  body.center-form {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  div.center-form {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  div.center-form > form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
</style>
<body class="center-form">
<div class="center-form">
  <form>
    <label for="nome">Seu Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```