# colocar DIV no centro da página

Tags: css

Como faço para essa 'div' ficar no centro da página?

```
.dialogbox { 
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
width: 550px;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: auto auto;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Preciso manter as propriedades 'position: absolute; top: 30px;', pois ela vai aparecer encima de outras div, e com uma margem no topo de 30px;

Comment: No centro com relação à largura então?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, horizontal

Comment: Cara, acho que é left: 50%

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/806/como-centralizar-horizontalmente-uma-div-dentro-de-outra ve se isso aqui não te ajuda

Comment: não da, ela fica torta, tenho que manter o tamanho da div de 'width: 550px;'

Comment: margin: 0 auto? http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html obs: isso é um lifehack

Comment: O problema está sendo devido o tamanho ser em px, então a centralização deverá ser em função ao tamanho da tela. Não é possível deixar como with em %? De uma olhada nisso: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/horizontal-centering-of-an-absolute-element/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```css
.dialogbox { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: calc(50vw - 275px);
  width: 550px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  
  background: red;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogbox"></div>
```

Comment: o que é '50vw'?

Comment: Metade da largura da janela. Se for relativo a outra coisa, pode usar 50% no lugar.