# Qual a melhor forma de centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente?

Tags: css, html, css3

Qual a melhor forma *(por "melhor" eu quero dizer: com maior compatibilidade possível entre browsers e o mais simples possível)* de posicionar um elemento no centro da página, vertical e horizontalmente e independentemente de resolução **utilizando somente CSS**?

Comment: Semi-duplicata? Na horizontal é fácil, na vertical ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conteudo-de-um-elemento?rq=1

Comment: Não é perfeitamente claro o que estás a perguntar! Existe um universo de maneiras de centrar elementos no ecrã via CSS, mas cada maneira é considerada solução adequada para um problema especifico. Da forma que tens a pergunta, não há como responder assertivamente.

Comment: @Zuul quem sabe valha a pena dar uma geral nas formas e seus pontos fracos e fortes ou usos.

Comment: @Kazzkiq postei uma resposta atendendo exatamente o que você quer.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Na minha opinião, a melhor solução é a que se adequa a muitos problemas. E isso ainda é relativo, pois o **problema** pode ser de compatibilidade ou até mesmo de uma altura fixa não poder ser determinada.

PA solução mais compatível não é necessariamente a melhor, pois compatibilidade é, muitas vezes, só questão de tempo. A melhor solução dependerá do projeto e do quão compatível ele deve ser, principalmente quando se está falando de alinhamento vertical.

Portanto, me restringirei a apresentar duas ótimas soluções, sem determinar qual é a melhor.

#### 1. `position`

Por ser compatível com browsers menos modernos, talvez essa seja a solução mais adequada na visão geral:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom: 0;
left: 0; right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

- Exige **altura fixa** (`height`)
- [Exemplo no JSBin](http://jsbin.com/IXafawE/1/edit)

#### 2. `translateY`

```css
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

- **Suporte:** IE9+
- Não exige **altura fixa**  (`height`)
- [Exemplo no JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uTOxObOm/1/edit)

Comment: +1 pelo uso da técnica com o ```translate``` que eu nunca tinha visto ser utilizada para este fim. Escolhi esta resposta pelo fato de ela ter o melhor suporte entre navegadores e ainda permitir que o elemento fique centralizado mesmo tendo ```width``` e ```height``` dinâmicos, o que é muito prático.

Comment: Genius!! @Diéssica

Comment: Perfect brow...

Answer (score 20):

Atualizando as respostas, já que temos novos métodos e a compatibilidade está maior, podemos usar o flexbox, que permite atingir o resultado com BEM menos código.

Veja como é simples:

```
.classe {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; //centraliza horizontalmente
    justify-content: center; //cetraliza verticalmente
}
```

Ele difere do comportamento normal, pois o `flexbox` influencia na direção em que as `divs` se alinham dentro dela, mas você pode resolver essas questões de layout com outras propriedades do `flexbox`.

Veja este exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/nhrdd278/

Answer (score 18):

Não há uma melhor forma, isso depende do que você estiver fazendo, por exemplo se quiser dar suporte a navegadores antigos sempre é melhor usar técnicas antigas, como tabelas:

```css
.elemento-principal {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.elemento-a-ser-centralizado {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Mas se seu alvo for navegadores modernos você pode usar propriedades que irão proporcionar maior controle dos elementos, por exemplo usando flexbox.

Leia [esse tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) para saber como centralizar elementos de tamanho qualquer;
Leia [esse tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/) caso queira saber como usar o flexbox (todos em inglês).

Answer (score 10):

Eu não vi, entre as respostas, a minha solução favorita:

HTML

```
<div class="block">    
    <div class="centered">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <p>But he stole up to us again, and suddenly clapping his hand on my shoulder, said&mdash;"Did ye see anything looking like men going towards that ship a while ago?"</p>
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Via http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Gosto dessa solução porque usando o :before o código fica limpo, eu posso usar as tags que forem mais semânticas para o caso e nunca tive problemas. O :before funciona a partir do IE8.

Answer (score 9):

Para mim, atualmente é a melhor forma pois permite elementos com altura não fixa, permitindo uma dinâmica maior.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <article>
      Centro
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

> O `align-items` faz o alinhamento vertical e o `justify-content`o horizontal.

```
section{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

article{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Vejam que em `.article` os valores de `height` e `width` podem ser alterados tanto para % quanto para pixel.

> Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZXdzb

Comment: Todos os navegadores suportam, desde que estejam atualizados.

Comment: Não entendi @renan. Poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 8):

A melhor maneira, simples e rápida.
Funciona 100% das vezes, em todos os navegadores.

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px; /* metade da largura */
    margin-top: -100px; /* metade da altura */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Inclusive IE6? ;)

Comment: IE6 voltou a virar um navegador então? =P

Comment: Tem um país com 2 bilhões de pessoas usando ;) pena de quem tem que dar suporte. Mas é só curiosidade mesmo. http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown

Comment: 4.4% de 6 bilhoes de pessoas na terra?

Answer (score 8):

Como a opção usando **Grid Layout** não foi citada em nenhuma das 19 respostas, vou deixar algumas instruções de como fazer usando o Grid Layout do CSS3.

Link da documentação oficial do  **Grid Layout** módulo 1 W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/

***Agora vamos aos exemplo:***

**1 -** Com `display:grid` no Pai e `margin:auto` no Filho

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid > p {
    position: absolute;
}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    background-color: plum;
}
.centro {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"><p>display: grid;</p>
    <div class="centro">margin: auto;</div>
</div>
```

---

**2 -** Com `display:grid` e `place-items:center` no Pai, não precisa de nada no Filho

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid > p {
    position: absolute;
}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: plum;
}
.centro {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"><p>display:grid; place-items:center</p>
    <div class="centro"></div>
</div>
```

---

**3 -** Com `display:grid` e `justify-content:center` e `align-items:center` no Pai (similar ao FlexBox), não precisa de nada no Filho

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid > p {
    position: absolute;
}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    background-color: plum;
}
.centro {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"><p>display: grid; justify-content: center; align-items: center; </p>
    <div class="centro"></div>
</div>
```

---

**4 -** Com `display:grid` no Pai, e `align-self:center` e `justify-self:center` Filho (similar ao FlexBox)

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid > p {
    position: absolute;
}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    background-color: plum;
}
.centro {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"><p>display: grid;</p>
    <div class="centro">align-self: center; justify-self: center;</div>
</div>
```

Compatibilidade com os browser de 87,5% no Mundo e 91% dos navegadores no Brasil segundo https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid * (10/04/2018)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

Se você souber o tamanho do elemento (ex: 200px 200px), você pode realizar o alinhamento da seguinte forma:

## CSS

```
#alinhamento{
    top:50%;
    position:absolute;
}

#elemento{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-200px;        
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="alinhamento">
    <div id="elemento">
    </div>
</div>
```

Caso o elemento tenha altura indeterminada, você deverá utilizar jquery para detectar o tamanho do elemento e posicionar no centro automaticamente.

Answer (score 7):

Usando CSS3:

```css
.conteudo-centro{
position: absolute;
z-index: 99999999;
left: 50%; top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="conteudo-centro">
    <h1>Opa, estamos no centro da tela!<br>
        Independente da resolução do dispositivo do usuário!  ;) </h1>
</section>
```

> Réplica no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/korzzus/wega9fun/);

Answer (score 6):

Na horizontal é tranquilo fazer somente através do CSS, já na vertical o mais próximo que conseguirá chegar é nesse [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/dt4ce/), a não ser que voce utilize um pouco de javascript/jquery

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 25% auto 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Só mais uma sugestão diante de tantas;
Utilize flex box;

```css
.flex-box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 400px;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
    <div>Conteudo centralizado aqui!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente solução, aliás, atualmente acredito ser a melhor usar flexbox

Answer (score 2):

Tente adicionar a seguinte classe ao elemento que você deseja centralizar:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Essa abordagem foi apresentada no Smashing Magazine no ano passado.
A única desvantagem é a necessidade do elemento possuir um `height` declarado.

Para maiores informações, acesse:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
    }

    .content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transform: translateY( -50% );
        -moz-transform: translateY( -50% );
        transform: translateY( -50% );
    }


<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Valor</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, numa questão com tantas respostas já dadas, fica difícil verificar o que de novo você está trazendo em relação às outras respostas, de forma que seja justo votar na sua resposta, seja positivamente ou negativamente...

Comment: Você poderia resumir o diferencial de sua resposta?

Comment: Tipo assim *"As outras respostas não previam que na situação X seria muito melhor fazer da forma Y, como vou apresentar a seguir..."*

Answer (score -1):

Se você está trabalhando com uma imagem `<img>`  pode utilizar o `vertical-align:middle`, porém nesse caso precisa se atentar ao `line-height`  do elemento que contém a imagem, ele deve ter o mesmo tamanho do elemento.

***Para imagens**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://a.disquscdn.com/next/7b3d8738/assets/img/noavatar92.png" alt="avatar disqus">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f00;
}

#container img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[veja pelo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LucasKauz/2B4A5/)**

***Método com conhecimento do `height`**

Se você tem a possibilidade de definir um `height` para esse elemento pode fazer utilizando o código citado num artigo da Smashing Magazine

**HTML**

```
<div>
  magix!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

***Solução em JavaScript com jQuery***

Agora se seu foco é um outro elemento você pode usar jQuery, usando lógica você irá deixar a distância do seu elemento com 50% das bordas, depois controlar o `margin`.

**[veja pelo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LucasKauz/j428q/2/)**

Comment: A solução é com jQuery, e você deve deixar isso claro em sua resposta. JavaScript `!=` jQuery.

Comment: Obrigado Diéssica, eu percebi o erro mas esqueci de atualizar :) Inclusive atualizei para deixar mais utilizável.

Answer (score -1):

A melhor forma é utilizando uma tabela.
Tu pode transformar uma DIV ou SPAN em tabela com CSS: "display: table;" e depois alinhar verticalmente com CSS:"vertical-align: middle;"
Eu tinha essa dúvida também. Fui procurar nos grandes sites e vi que Facebook faz assim.
Não é a maneira mais elegante, mas eu acho a mais certa.

Answer (score -2):

Pra mim uma das melhores forma é de colocar o css

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
```

Depois coloca margin negativa, sendo a metade do tamanho do seu elemento

```
margin-top:-200px
margin-left:-200px
```

A desvantagem é que o objeto tem que ser do tamanho fixo, nesse exemplo o objeto tem 400px de altura e 400px de largura. Lembrando que o display deve ser absolute.

Answer (score -3):

Basta fixar um tamanho no elemento e dar um margin : auto;

```
div {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Como foi dito não existe uma forma "melhor" de se fazer isso, tudo depende do projeto..
Eu costumo usar isso:

```
seletor{margin: 0 auto;}
```

Mas como eu disse, varia muito de projeto para projeto.

Comment: Isso centraliza apenas horizontalmente.

Comment: Olá André, pois é. Equivoco meu! Obrigado pelo toque...