# Centralizando modal bootstrap em tela mobile

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3, modal

Estou tentando centralizar uma `modal` do bootstrap no centro da tela de um mobile, porém o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou seguindo este exemplo, porém não está funcionando:

[Como centralizar um Modal Box na Horizontal e Vertical com CSS3? É possível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100711/como-centralizar-um-modal-box-na-horizontal-e-vertical-com-css3-%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel)

Abaixo os códigos da minha modal e CSS:

```
<div id="modal-facens" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">FACENS - Faculdade de Engenharia de Sorocaba</h4>
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sorocaba/SP <br>
          <a href="http://www.facens.br/" target="_blank">http://www.facens.br/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                Cursando o último ano de Engenharia da Computação. Teste Commit. Teste Commit DEV
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn-info btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

.modal {
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
  }
}
.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido.

Alterei o código CSS com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

O resultado que eu queria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]