# Centralizar DIV verticalmente sem altura fixa no CSS

Tags: css3, css

Existem diversas maneiras para centralizar o conteúdo de uma `<div>` verticalmente. Entretanto, quando tratamos de uma altura que não seja em pixels, as pessoas começam a pensar se há um método eficiente para isso.

Criei uma forma que achei eficiente e vim aqui a procura de alguém que ofereça uma proposta melhor, pois uma das maiores dificuldades que um front-end encontra hoje é **centralizar um conteúdo de uma div que não tenha altura em pixels**.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <div>
      <p>Centro</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

article > div{
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

> Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZXdzb

Comment: Possivel relacionada : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente

Answer (score 3):

Se for considerar o uso de flexbox, como no seu exemplo, uma solução é usar a propriedade [**`align-items`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/align-items):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width:  100%
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div>olá</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigado por compartilhar essas propriedades Renan.

Comment: @ZenoJunior Mas espere por outras respostas, calma rapaz.

Comment: Ah, estou começando aqui. Já desmarquei...

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa alternativa é:

```
section{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
article > div{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

(para facilitar a leitura, não inseri os prefixos necessários para o transform)

Usando este método, eu costumo setar uma largura máxima para a `div`.