# Alinhar uma div dentro de outra verticalmente

Tags: html, css3, div

Meu objetivo é obter esse alinhamento vertical:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso alinhar vertical e horizontalmente os conteúdos das `div's` `busca` e `buscaImovel` consecutivamente.

O alinhamento horizontal funciona mas o alinhamento vertical não funciona.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obs.: Tentei colocar position: relative; na div busca mas tanto busca quanto buscaImovel sumiram.

CSS

```
.busca {
    top:370px;
    height:240px;
    background-image:url(../../_img/fundo_ap.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}


 .buscaImovel {
        position:relative;
        top:20px;
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        -moz-border-radius:  20px 20px 20px 20px;
        border-radius:  20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    .campoBusca {
        position:relative;  
        top:20px;
    }
    .camposBusca, .alternativaEscolha {
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="busca">
  <div class="buscaImovel"><br />
    <h1 >Pesquise pelo imóvel que deseja</h1>
    <form action="busca.php"  method="post">
      <div class="camposBusca">
         <label class="labelPequeno">Tipo</label><br />
         <select class="typeTextMedio" id="tipo" name="tipo" required>
           <option value="">Escolha o Tipo</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="camposBusca">
         <label class="labelPequeno">Bairro</label><br />
         <select class="typeTextMedio" id="bairro" name="bairro" required>
           <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="camposBusca">    
         <button>Buscar</button>
      </div>

    </form>

  <div style="height:15px;"></div>

    <div class="alternativaEscolha">
       <a href="buscaAvancada.php"><label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC;">Busca Avançada</label></a>
    </div>

    <div class="alternativaEscolha">
    <!--abrir popUp-->
       <a href="buscaCodigo.php"><label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC;">Busca por Código</label></a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Da forma que está, o conteúdo da `div busca`, quando em uma tela de `320px` X `480px`, ultrapassa a div de baixo e fica uma bagunça

Comment: Você quer que fique no meio verticalmente? coloque "position: relative;" no .busca

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente

Comment: position: relative.levou as divs para lugares longe das suas posições originais e uma nem ficou dentro da outra

Comment: Eu não consegui centralizar ms consegui empurrar para baixo que não é uma forma correta de trabalhar fazendo na div buscaImovel position:relative; e top:20px;. Mas se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço! Não posso colocar postion absolut conforme orientação do lik acima porque senão serei forçado a alterar todo o css por causa da posição das diversas outras divs.