# Alinhar div verticalmente no Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

Estou estudando css e me desafiei a criar uma reprodução de uma imagem que segue abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui fazer algo parecido, porém não consegui funcionar da mesma forma no Internet Explorer, vi alguns exemplos utilizando `display: table` e `position: relative` porém não obtive sucesso numa visualização crossbroser (exatamente no Internet Explorer 11).

Segue abaixo imagem da visualização no Internet Explorer 11 (Windows Seven Professional):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: o meu problema está no alinhamento vertical das bolas 3 e 4.

Acredito que o problema seja em relação a estrutura do meu HTML.

Segue o meu exemplo:

```css
* {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .main {
/*         background-color: #bebebe; */
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .row {
        width: 100%;
/*         border: 2px solid #000; */
        text-align: center;
    }
    
  

    
    .main .mini-ball {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
    }    
    
    .row .mini-ball-top-left {
        background-color: #c5e9ad;
    }    
    
    .row .mini-ball-top-right {
        background-color: #b2dcf9;
    } 
    
    .row .mini-ball-middle-left {
        background-color: #e45e47;
        margin-right: 40px
    } 
    
    .row .mini-ball-middle-right {
        background-color: #e45e47;
        margin-left: 40px
    } 
    
    .row .mini-ball-bottom-left {
        background-color: #b2dcf9;
    } 
    
    .row .mini-ball-bottom-right {
        background-color: #c5e9ad;
    }    
    
    .row .mini-ball-top-right,
    .row .mini-ball-top-left {
        margin: 0px 40px -20px;
    }   
    
    .mini-ball-bottom-right,
     .mini-ball-bottom-left {
        margin: -80px 40px;
        position: relative;
         top: -20px
    }    
    
    .main .main-ball {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #2171af;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }  

    .main .main-ball .content {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }   
    
    .row .align-vertical {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-top-left">1</div>
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-top-right">2</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-middle-left align-vertical">3</div>
         <div class="main-ball">
            <div class="content">Intranet</div>
         </div>
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-middle-right align-vertical">4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-bottom-left">5</div>
         <div class="mini-ball mini-ball-bottom-right">6</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Exemplo gerado no codepen: http://codepen.io/adrianoavelino/pen/rLMVWb?editors=1100

Qual a melhor estrutura HTML ou técnica para obter esse alinhamento vertical?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a melhor forma de centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente)

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do elemento:
`<div class="mini-ball mini-ball-top-left">1</div>`

Eu adicionei uma nova div que vai conter o conteúdo dela, ficando assim:
`<div class="mini-ball mini-ball-top-left"><div class="conteudo">1</div></div>`

Agora para funcionar corretamente basta adicionar o `position:relative;` na classe **.mini-ball** e criar o copiar o CSS da classe **.conteudo**.

Segue ele abaixo:

```
.main .mini-ball .conteudo {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);  
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente a solução é para o conteúdo das bolas 3 e 4 (técnica que já está sendo utilizada na classe `.main .main-ball .content` ) e o meu problema está em relação o alinhamento vertical da bola e somente no navegador Internet Explorer. Adicionei na pergunta uma imagem de como está ficando no Internet Explorer.