# Alinhar ao centro

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra deixar centralizado o chat.

```
<iframe src="https://www2.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=2392843&boxtag=uStqza" width="75%" height="450" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SO Adriana, por favor faça um [tour] para conhecer melhor a ferramenta, desta maneira você tera conseguira criar perguntas concisas para que nós possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a melhor forma de centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente)

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma **div**, coloca o chat dentro.
No **CSS** você  faz:

```
#div
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

No **JavaScript** você faz:

```
function centraliza(){
  var div = document.getElemenById('div');
  div.style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (div.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
}
```

`centraliza();` "Você coloca essa função no onload da pagina e/ou no onresize também"

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar `style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;"` ao `iframe`:

```
<iframe style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" src="https://www2.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=2392843&boxtag=uStqza" width="75%" height="450" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

**Exemplo:**

```html
<iframe style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" src="https://www2.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=2392843&boxtag=uStqza" width="75%" height="450" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

cria uma div ou class e lá no css vc coloca:
exemplo com class:
no html:

```
<div class="chat">
<iframe src="https://www2.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=2392843&boxtag=uStqza" width="75%" height="450" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

no css:

```
.chat{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;

}
```