# Alinhar divs verticalmente ao centro (middle)

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
img {
 border: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}
div.cabecalho {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
 border:.1px solid #000000;
}
div.cabecalho div.logo,
div.cabecalho div.whats,
div.cabecalho div.contato,
div.cabecalho div.medias {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 line-height:70%;
}
div.cabecalho div.logo {
 width:43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecalho">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/logoFuneraria.png" alt="Logo"/>
  </div>
  <div class="whats"></div>
  <div class="contato"></div>
  <div class="medias"></div>
</div>
```

O Objetivo é que as 4 `divs` dentro da `div` fiquem `inline` e alinhadas verticalmente ao centro (middle).

Onde estou errando?

Objetivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Carlos está meio confuso de entender o que vc quer. Teria como colocar uma imagem do layout que vc precisa, ou explicar melhor o que seria esse alinhamento que vc quer.

Comment: Sim. Tenho a div cabecalho. Ok? Tenho 4 divs filhas dentro dela (logo, whats, contato e media). Ok? Essas 4 divs estão com display inline para ficarem em fila e não em bloco. OK? Então, só que o alinhamento vertical das 4 divs filhas, gostaria que fosse centralizado em relação à div pai. Melhorou?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a melhor forma de centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente)

Comment: O problema está no caso de eu ter 4 divs para centralizar e não apenas 1 igual aos exemplos dados no outro post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `align-self` do **flexbox**!

Para isso, você precisaria setar que a `div` pai é `display: flex` para poder fazer a distribuição dos elementos de forma homogênea  e na `div` filha para poder alinhar seus elementos ao centro!

Para exemplificar, fiz um rápido esboço no [Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorjordan95/pen/OZbEGb) para ajudar!

Comment: entendi. Mas será que dessa forma tem como colocar responsivo? Isto é, as colunas, à medida em que a tela vai diminuindo, vais indo para baixo umas das outras e mantendo o tamanho?

Comment: Para deixar responsivo basta você usar `Media Query` e ir definindo as propriedades de acordo com a resolução! Eu alterei o [Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorjordan95/pen/OZbEGb) adicionando alguns breakpoints para tablet e desktop.

Comment: muito obrigado!