# Cálculo de top no scss

Tags: html, scss

Tenho um container que possui um height variável, dependendo da resolução do computador.

Preciso calcular quando de top devo utilizar para que o conteúdo fique centralizado.

Tentei algo como:

```
.container {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(((100% - height) / 2));
}
```

Porém não deu certo. Alguém sabe como faz esse tipo de calculo no scss?

Comment: Seu cal tem um par de () a mais... Deveria ser apensa calc((100% - height) / 2). De qualquer forma não sei se isso vai resolver. Na verdade acredito que essa não seja a melhor forma de alinhar um elemento verticalmente....

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consegui entender muito bem o que você pretende fazer. Você quer um tamanho de **height** variável para que o conteúdo dentro dele não saia para fora é isso ? É só excluir o **height**. Não há necessidade dele. Mas agora se você precisa de um valor em específico, você pode ir colocar a quantidade de pixels até ter o resultado que deseja. Se você quer ter um espaço do topo, dentro do seu **container**, você pode usar apenas um **Padding-top: Quantidade de pixels;**

Comment: Aqui tem mais de 20 resposta de como fazer esse alinhamento, alguma delas deve te servir https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente

Comment: O `transform: translateY(-50%)` com `top: 50%` talvez possa resolver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190922/how-to-calculate-with-scss-variables-from-function

Answer (score 0):

Para você utilizar [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp), você deve sempre saber o tamanho das coisas que insere, não da para colocar somente `height` dentro de `calc()`, que ele não irá retornar o valor para o cálculo.

Ele também deve estar com `position` em `absolute`, pois senão, o elemento irá ficar fora do alinhamento. Nesse exemplo, ao determinar valores para o width e height, eu trabalhei com a metade dos valores para o alinhamento:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">teste</div>
```

Outra opção, ao meu ver mais fácil, é utilizar o `translate(-50%,-50%)`, em que você pode determinar livremente o tamanho do elemento que você quer, que ele irá fazer o alinhamento automaticamente:

```css
.container {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">teste</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para alinhar verticalmente eu sempre uso:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Agora para que você calcule o top dependendo da resoluçao de um monitor talvez usar apenas um top com porcentagem seria o suficiente. Se não, desculpe é tudo que sei.