# Como centralizar todos os elementos de uma página HTML verticalmente?

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo uma página utilizando `bootstrap` e preciso que o `carousel` fique centralizado junto com as imagens no meio da página, tanto horizontalmente (já feito) quanto verticalmente, pois no celular, a imagem aparece lá no topo.
**Obs:** já tentei usar o comando `vertical-align: middle` e infelizmente não funcionou.

**CSS**

```
*
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body, html
{
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00ccff , #00cc00);
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR IPAD LANDSCAPTE */
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR IPAD PORTRAIT */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR ALL MOBILE DEVICES : HAVING LESS THAN 767 RESOLUTION */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* MEDIA QUERY FOR EXTRA SMALL : IPHONE LANDSCAPE & PORTRAIT DEVICES */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}

@viewport {
  width: device-width ;
  zoom: 1.0 ;
}

#myCarousel, .carousel-inner
{
  height: 100%;
}

#primeira_imagem
{
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: block
}
```

*Visualização da página:*
[image: Página através do computador]

[image: Página através do celular]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a melhor forma de centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente)

Comment: Até consegui alinhar tudo usando o método do segundo comentário, mas agora nasceu outro problema. Os slides do carousel estão nascendo no topo e se alinhando no meio quando ocorre a troca de slides, causando um "efeito esquisito", não ocorre a troca de slides fluidamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para o seu caso o [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) vai te ajudar bastante.

Você pode criar uma div para envolver o seu carousel e definir seu tamanho. Essa div irá receber as seguintes propriedades css:

.Wrapper{
display: flex;

justify-content: center;

align-items:center;

}

Veja o exemplo no [CodePen](https://codepen.io/denner-luan/pen/poyJLRw)

Pesquisa também [Grid CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Esses dois conjuntos de propriedades: Flexbox e Grid vai fazer com que você posicione os elementos mais facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca esse css no body

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center