# Como especificar uma class CSS para textos que quebram linha em um elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Na maioria das vezes que trabalho com textos dentro de elementos **HTML**, utilizo um recurso em **CSS** chamado `line-height`. Suponhamos que a altura de um elemento específico seja de `50px`, logo, coloco o `line-height` com `50px` também para que o texto fique centralizado. Pois bem, quando esse texto quebra linha, ou seja, acaba sendo maior que o tamanho do meu elemento, não fica uma coisa muito legal. Existe uma forma em **CSS** que verifique se meu texto quebrou linha para que eu possa adicionar uma propriedade `line-height` diferente?

**Exemplo de um texto em que fica centralizado corretamente, contendo pouco texto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora, um exemplo de como o texto fica quando é um pouco maior, ou seja, que ultrapassa o limite de meu elemento:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que na imagem acima, o texto caiu e manteve o tamanho do line-height. Isso é ruim pois acaba ultrapassando o limite de altura de meu elemento.

**Agora, como gostaria que ficasse quando o texto cai pra linha debaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria esse o problema, possibilidades com javascript não são descartadas também caso alguém tenha uma solução bacana.

Comment: Imagino que não... imagina, se isso fosse possível você poderia acabar entrando em loop de CSS.

Comment: Paulo, sua pergunta está confusa. Organize as informações, coloque exemplos práticos e deixe o seu objetivo mais claro.

Comment: Eu achei sua pergunta direta, você quer usar uma condicional dentro do CSS. Lendo isso aqui você vai encontrar sua resposta -> http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/

Comment: Reformulei minha pergunta com algumas imagens demonstrativas Caio. Talvez agora melhore o entendimento.

Comment: Acho melhor você usar [outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conteudo-de-um-elemento) [técnica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/melhor-forma-de-centralizar-um-elemento-vertical-e-horizontalmente) para centralizar o texto verticalmente.

Comment: Com certeza não precisa JavaScript. Existem MUITAS alternativas para centralização vertical. Muitas mesmo. Existem até fãs de `display: table`!

Comment: O uso de display:table; no elemento pai, e uso das propriedades vertical-align:middle; e display:table-cell; no elemento que contém o texto, seria uma boa prática?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu CSS você vai precisar declarar altura, display como table-cell e vertical-align middle.

```
.seletor {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Veja o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/QPdLx/1/

Answer (score 3):

Sugestão:

- Diminua o `line-height`do texto, deixando na medida da tua última imagem, onde o texto com quebra de linha aparece bonito.
- Envolva esse texto num `div` ou outro elemento, e aplique `vertical-align: middle` ao mesmo. (Talvez precise um `display: inline-block`.)
- No elemento que envolve tudo (a data, o texto, o padding), aí sim, atribua um `line-height` da mesma altura do `height` para que o alinhamento vertical seja aplicado.