# Como pegar a posição de um elemento que usa a propriedade CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine que eu tenha uma popup que é centralizada com `transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` *(se você tiver dúvida sobre essa solução, pode ver mais sobre ela **[aqui](https://gist.github.com/kazzkiq/8693631)**, adaptada [**destas**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2939/1754) [**respostas**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166/1754))*.

Até ai tudo bem, o elemento é centralizado corretamente, mas digamos que por algum motivo eu precise descobrir a posição exata dele no `document` do navegador (para implementar um *drag'n-drop* por exemplo). Eu tentei as propriedades `offsetTop` e `offsetLeft` mas elas retornam a posição do elemento sem os transforms, ou seja, é uma posição "fake".

Minha pergunta é, existe alguma propriedade que retorne os valores **reais** de um elemento que seja posicionado usando `translate`?

Segue um exemplo para melhor entendimento: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/395E7/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como foi comentado, as propriedades `offsetTop` e `offsetLeft` não retornam a posição exata do elemento quando ele usa a propriedade CSS `translate()`.

A única propriedade que eu tenho conhecimento que funcione com `translate()` é a [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect), e o mais interessante: Ela é antiga e **totalmente cross-browser** (funciona até no IE6).

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
var el = document.getElementById('popup'),
    pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();

alert('Top: '+pos.top+'\nLeft: '+pos.left); // retorna a posição REAL do elemento
```

E um exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sxGg/)

Answer (score -1):

Quando você usa o translate, a posição do elemento fica centralizada.

Desse forma você precisa pegar o `width` do elemento e dividir por dois, assim você tem a posição `left`;

Para pegar o `top`, basta pegar o `height` do elemento e dividir por dois.

Comment: Favor, o código na resposta. Da forma que está não é considerado uma resposta muito válida.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Rafael! Sugiro que você explique melhor sua solução (um exemplo funcionando seria ótimo!) e que você não compartilhe dados de contato em respostas - ah, e que [faça o tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o SOpt! :)