# Alinhamento vertical em um div com position:absolute

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

gostaria de saber se é possivel realizar o `vertical-align` em uma div com position absolute? Segue o código para analise:

```
.teste {
    background: #F00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Link com o codigo: http://jsfiddle.net/douglas1551/pzryoqjz/

Valeu!

Comment: queres alinhar o conteúdo da div ao centro?

Comment: talvez essa pergunta o ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conte%C3%BAdo-de-um-elemento

Comment: CesarMiguel não necessariamente, quero poder utilizar o vertical-align como uma todo( top, middle, bottom )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso você precisa colocar o **texto** entre `<p></p>`:

```
<div class="teste">
   <p>Hue BR<br/>Hue BR<br/>HUe BR</p>
</div>
```

O modo que você fez, só funcionaria se fosse em tabela:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td aling="middle" height="100" style="background:red">Hue BR<br/>Hue<br/>HUe BR</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: é Luiz descobrir que só é possivel usando o display:table-cell( uma decpeção ) mas faz parte. Valeu pela resposta XD

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, só fica um pouco mais extenso. É preciso criar uma outra DIV dentro daquela que terá posição absoluta:

```
<div class="teste">
  <div class="testeInterna">
     Hue BR<br>Hue BR<br>HUe BR
  </div>
<div>
```

...e passar todas as propriedades para ela (exceto position:absolute)

```
.teste {
  position:absolute;
}

.testeInterna{
   background: #F00;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display:table-cell;
}
```