# Como faço para centralizar o conteudo de um elemento verticalmente?

Tags: css

Bom, eu pretendo centralizar o conteudo de uma div, a nivel vertical.

A minha div, está dentro de uma outra div que é o container:

DIV Container:

```
container{
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
width:80%;  
position:relative;
height:100%;
}
```

DIV que pretendo centralizar Verticalmente:

```
.status{
position:absolute;
width:55%;
height:6%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0.1px;
margin-top:16.8%;
margin-left:44.8%;
font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif;
}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como centralizar verticalmente o conteúdo de um elemento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conte%c3%bado-de-um-elemento)

Answer (score 1):

Eu particularmente gosto bastante de usar `calc`, e aqui eu fiz da seguinte forma:

`.div-pai .div-filha {
  top: calc(metade da altura da div pai - metade da altura da div filha)
}`

Segue:

```css
.a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.a .b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  top: calc(100px - 20px);
  left: calc(150px - 50px);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não há sentido em heigth:100% em uma div pai, a não ser que ele esteja em outro container com algum heigth setado, uma alternativa é o uso da unidade vh que se baseia na altura da sua janela, ou seja 100vh = 100%; porém é um elemento estático, medidas como vw podem fazer um trabalho relativo, medidas como essa não tem suporte a navegadores antigos principalmente o navegador padrão do android, por esse motivo recomendo estudar técnicas como flexbox.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
width:80%;  
position:relative;
height:100vh; /* regule aqui */
border: 1px black solid;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.status{
//position:absolute;
width:55%;
height:20px;
border: 1px black solid;
margin-left:50%;
font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="status">
      teste
    </div>
    
</div>
```