# Alinhamento vertical com CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando exibir uma imagem e ao lado dela um texto. Meu problema é que esse texto deve estar alinhado com a parte de baixo da imagem, porém só aparece alinhada ao topo.
Já tentei muitos códigos e acabei chegando neste que também não funciona:

```
    <div class="row" >
        <div style="max-width:150px; float:left">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src=data:image.jpg alt="" />
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; border:1px solid; height:inherit;"><h4>Alguem de Teste</h4></div>
    </div>
```

Alguém sabe dizer como faço isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**EDITADO:**

Renan tentei seguir esse modelo que comentou:

[Como centralizar verticalmente o conteúdo de um elemento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conte%C3%BAdo-de-um-elemento)

Quase deu certo, mas aí tem algumas diferenças que não consegui personalizar. Primeiro eu não sei o tamanho da div pai(container) ela terá a altura da imagem em seu interior que pode variar um pouco. E ao contrário do exemplo tenho 2 conteúdos que devem ficar um ao lado do outro e não sei como conciliar isso com o "position: absolute;" usado no exemplo.

Comment: @Renan será que pode me ajudar com as 2 diferenças que tenho desse exemplo que indicou? Eu tentei aqui mas não consegui e editei a pergunta para apontar 2 pontos em que fiquei sem saber como solucionar.

Comment: vertical-align não funciona?

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo pelo que li (não sei muio de html e css) o vertical-aline só funciona em tabela. E um macete pra contornar isso é colocar o "display:table-cell". Mas não estava funcionando.  Obs... fiz como o Guilherme sugeriu usando "display: inline-block" e deu certinho.

Comment: O vertical-align funciona pra elementos caixa tbm, como divs por exemplo, e não só pra table, mas que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de `table-cell` e `float` você pode usar `inline-block` combinado com `vertical-align: bottom;`, um exemplo:

```html
<div class="row" >
    <div style="max-width:150px; display: inline-block;">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 100%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPI0G.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; border:1px solid; height:inherit;"><h4>Alguem de Teste</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute;` e `bottom: 0;` na caixa de texto, e coloque `position: relative;` e `display: inline-block;` no pai, que no caso é `.row`, segue código:

```css
.row{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box-image{
    max-width: 150px;
    float: left;
    
    /*para fins de teste, ignore*/
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.box-txt{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
   
    /*você também precisará definir uma largura para a caixa de texto*/
    width: 113px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" >
    <div class="box-image">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src=data:image.jpg alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="box-txt"><h4>Alguem de Teste</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas eu não conhecia esse "display: inline-block" (na verdade sei muito pouco de html e css). Apena substitui como o Guilherme sugeriu e funcionou.

Comment: @AlamBique tranquilo hahahah, eu fiz quase a mesma coisa que ele, só troquei a logica do `vertical-align: bottom;` por um objeto `absolute` filho de outro `relative` com `bottom: 0;`