# Como faço para centralizar verticalmente esse input?

Tags: html5, css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][![

```css
div#newsletter{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    div#newsletter input{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px #606060 solid;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
div#newsletter input.botao{
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsletter">
            <form>
                <h1>Quer receber nossas promoções?</h1>
                <input type="text" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Digite seu email">
                <input type="button" value="Receber" class="botao">
            </form>
        </div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH61G.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH61G.png)

Comment: Mas já está centralizado jovem! Explica melhor isso ai

Comment: centralizar verticalmente

Comment: Outra duplicada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conte%c3%bado-de-um-elemento

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi, mas é assim, você pode usar a tag  para centralizar no documento html, ou se quiser centralizar dentro de alguma div, form etc algum elemento, você usa um css:

```
.element-container { /*Aqui no caso é o form*/
    width: 300px; /*Aqui você limita o tamanho da largura*/
}

.element-child { /*e aqui você coloca a largura de 100% do elemento pai que é o form */
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: vertical;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3399cc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input.txt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #3399ff;
  outline: none;
}

input {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsletter">
            <center>
              <h1>Quer receber nossas promoções?</h1>
              <form>
                  Nome:
                  <input class="txt" type="text" name="nome" value="" placeholder="">
                  Email:
                  <input class="txt" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder=""><br><br>
                  <input class="btn" type="button" value="Receber" class="botao">
              </form>
            </center>
        </div>
```

Comment: Quase isso kkkk, mas eu estava falando de como alinhar verticalmente, como deixar o input no meio da div, tanto vertical, como horizontal (horizontal já está)